# Compress a Integer to a Base64 upper/lower case character in Ruby (to make an Encoded Short URL)

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, base64

I have a member number like "123456" that I want to encode into the shortest string I can for use in a url shortener (without a database).

The standard characters `A-Z`, `a-z` and `0-9` give me 62 characters to work with, easily being 64 charaters if I add two special characters like `_` and `!` for example.

How can I convert the any number up to say 64 to be a single character.
So something like.

```rb
encode(1)  # -> a
encode(10) # -> j
encode(26) # -> z
encode(27) # -> A
encode(52) # -> Z
encode(123456) # -> eJA
```

So I could have any number .. and return a shorter encoded string.

Attempt with things like the built in Base64 are returning a string that's as long as the input.

```
Base64.encode64("10") # -> "MTA=\n" ... I want the output to be 1 character not 6!!
```

How can I encode integers to be a shorter base 64 string?

Edit:
Oh and it was implied but I totally forgot to say, how do I also then de-encode back to the original input?

```rb
decode('a')  # -> 1
decode('j') # -> 10
decode('z') # -> 26
decode('A') # -> 27
decode('Z') # -> 52
decode('eJA') # -> 123456
```

Comment: *"MTA=\n" ... I want the output to be 1 character not 6* - 1. the '\n'  does not belong to the base64 string, the base64 string is just "MTA=". 2. You're not encoding an integer value but a 2 characters long string "10".  3. Base64 encodes bytes, but a single base64 character only represents 6 bits, so there'll always be at least 2 base64 characters plus padding ("=" to fill up to 4 characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others here have said ruby's Base64 encoding is not the same as converting an integer to a string using a base of 64. Ruby provides an elegant converter for this but the maximum base is `base-36`. (See @jad's answer).

Below brings together everything into two methods for encoding/decoding as `base-64`.

```rb
def encode(int)
  chars = [*'A'..'Z', *'a'..'z', *'0'..'9', '_', '!']
  digits = int.digits(64).reverse
  digits.map { |i| chars[i] }.join
end
```

And to decode

```rb
def decode(str)
  chars = [*'A'..'Z', *'a'..'z', *'0'..'9', '_', '!']
  digits = str.chars.map { |char| value = chars.index(char) }.reverse
  output = digits.each_with_index.map do |value, index|
    value * (64 ** index)
  end
  output.sum
end
```

Give them a try:

```rb
puts output = encode(123456) #=> "eJA"
puts decode(output) #=> 123456
```

The compression is pretty good, an integer around 99 Million (99,999,999) encodes down to 5 characters ("1pOkA").

To gain the extra compression of including upper and lower case characters using base-64 is inherantly case-sensetive. If you are wanting to make this case-insensetive, using the built in base-36 method per Jad's answer is the way to go.

*Credit to @stefan for help with this.*

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's base-64 (a numeral system) and [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (an encoding for binary data). Ruby's built-in `Base64` module converts data (strings) to and from Base64 encoding.

I assume that you on the other hand want to convert a number from base-10 to base-64 and then use a custom alphabet (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, !) to represent each digit.

Your input number `123456` is in base-10. You can convert it to base-64 via [`digits`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Integer.html#digits-method) – which returns an array of digits:

```
number = 123456
digits = number.digits(64).reverse
#=> [30, 9, 0]
```

And then [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#map-method) each digit to its corresponding character:

```
chars = [*'A'..'Z', *'a'..'z', *'0'..'9', '_', '!']

digits.map { |i| chars[i] }.join
#=> "eJA"
```

Comment: Looks interesting... and how would I decode back to the original input? (sorry I didnt explicity ask before)

Comment: @Evolve convert the symbols in `"eJA"` back to `[30, 9, 0]`. Then calculate the number via 30×64² + 9×64 + 0 = 123456.

Comment: Ok I've had a play, and can get from `str = "eJA"` back to `[30, 9, 0]` with this:  `str.chars.map { |c| chars.index(c) }`.  Im not that clear on how the last bit works.. can you provide code to do the last bit (that expands beyond just covering 123456).

Comment: I'd like to have yours be the canonical answer, would you be happy to push the results into two methods? Maybe `def encode(int)` and `def decode(str)`. That'll make it much easier for future visitors.

Comment: @Evolve I'm currently not available for freelance work :-) But here's a hint: if you reverse the array you'll get `[0, 9, 30]`. From there you can map each element to `value * 64**index` and sum the results.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with "base-64" for character conversion, but I've used base 36 a number of times in the past, using the built-in ruby `#to_s` and `#to_i` routines:

```
2.7.2 :007 > 340.to_s(36)
 => "9g"
2.7.2 :008 > "9g".to_i(36)
 => 340
```

I'm not 100% sure which characters you would use for your base character set. "Base 36" is all alphas (26) and all numerics (10).

Comment: Thanks! For later visitors, I found the api for this and 36 seems to be the max it goes up to. https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i

Comment: Thanks so much for this, an elegant use of the Ruby standard library was my hope, but since it only goes up to base 36, I cant acccept this one. But I reckon this will be super useful for future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: The good thing about base 36 is that it's not case sensitive, and really useful for "compressing" numbers for output to a barcode or equivalent. It also uses a character set that will always be valid ... If you were going to do this manually, you might be best off working the magic applied to the selected answer, but then base 64 seems arbitrary